# Accessing controller method from ResultExecutingContext in ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes, httpcontext

I'm writing an attribute where I want to access a method on the class that the controller that has the attribute on one of its actions derives from. That's quite a mouthful, so let me explain:

- My controller derives from a class that has a method with the following signature: `protected bool IsSearchEngine()` (the base class itself derives from `Controller`)
- One of the actions on my controller has an attribute
- The attribute derives from `ActionFilterAttribute` and overloads `OnResultExecuting`.
- The `OnResultExecuting` method has a `ResultExecutingContext` parameter.

**How can I access `IsSearchEngine()` through the `ResultExecutingContext`?**

---

**UPDATE:** So far, I've gotten the compiler and Intellisense to accept this:

```
(filterContext.Controller as MyAssembly.Controllers.BaseControllerClass).IsSearchEngine()
```

Is that the right way to do this? I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By casting the `resultExecutingContext.Controller` to `BaseController` you can access through all Property and Methods of your base controller, but the protection level of your Method `IsSearchEngine()` you cannot access it.  If you declared your `IsSerchEngine()` by `public` you can just call it as `((BaseController)resultExecutingContext.Controller).IsSearchEngine()`